# Extend timeout for graceful shutdown in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

#### Setup

I am using `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register()` to register a method for gracefully shutting down an Azure App Service (.NET 6.0, Windows 64 Bit, managed pipeline version: "Integrated") when stopped using the stop button in the Azure portal. For testing purposes, I added the following loop to the callback method to simulate a slow shutdown:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) // wait 5 mins
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Console.WriteLine($"Waited {(i + 1) * 1} s.");
}
```

#### Problem

Clicking the stop button on the App Service's page in the Azure Portal correctly calls the callback, but still kills the process after approximately 30 s, as can be seen from the log. The desired behavior would be to see the full 300 s logged in the output before the process exits.

#### What I tried so far

Increasing shutdown timeout in `Program.Main`:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)) // give enough time for graceful shutdown
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Increasing shutdown time limit in `web.config`:

```
 <aspNetCore shutdownTimeLimit="600" processPath=".\MyService.exe" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

None of these solutions work.

Comment: Rather than trying to fight these timeouts, it's often a better investment of time and energy to see which current parts of your shutdown process can be moved to other parts of your application's lifecycle. Getting any notification of shutdown is a *luxury*, it's not the time to start performing "expensive" operations.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sure, but not applicable in this particular case.

Comment: This seems to be an active bug: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39139

Comment: @sbfrancies No, this is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain the system isn't made for you to simply put a loop that halts in shutdown. It will at some point realise there is not point in finishing the thread, and terminate it.

Try and make an API with a long response time, or something else that isn't a simple loop. And then use that instead.

What you've decided to try out here is a waste of resources, and without proper documentation on the process; you should try other methods, and if the issue persists, make an issue.